# Export draw.io with specified width and height

Tags: app.diagrams.net

How can I export a draw.io diagram with a specified width and height? I tried to export it by specifying a width and height in the dialog box, but it ends up with cropped borders close to the diagram. Happened on all formats - pdf, png, jpg and gif.

Comment: Did you try increasing the Borderwidth value in the export dialog as well?